# Installed Win7, installed Thunderbird, copied my old Thunderbird mail profile over

Tags: windows, thunderbird

...Thunderbird is now convinced it's running (it's not; I checked the task manager).

How do I fix this? I'm guessing I have to delete/change some flag in the profile that says it's running.

Comment: You probably have a stale lock file to delete. Go in to the profile directory you copied and look for a file name that includes "lock" in it. Move that outside of the profile directory (or simplify restoring it if that doesn't do it)...

Comment: No such file was seen.

Comment: So, what's the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: "Thunderbird is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Thunderbird process, or restart your system." And, as stated - I checked. There is no running "Thunderbird" or like-named process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved through here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_in_use#Solutions

Needed to edit the profiles.ini file to point to the existing profile.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the below helps, you can [resume where I started, and left off](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20%22Thunderbird%20is%20already%20running,%20but%20is%20not%20responding.%20To%20open%20a%20new%20window,%20you%20must%20first%20close%20the%20existing%20Thunderbird%20process,%20or%20restart%20your%20system%22)....

**<strike>Stolen</strike> *Acquired* [from here](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/services/its/servicessupport/deskside/linuxworkstationguide/faqsandtips/thunderbirdprofilelocked/):**

- You have Thunderbird running somewhere already. You can't run Thunderbird on more than one computer at the same time with the same profile. If you are logged in to another computer and are running Thunderbird there then this is the cause of the message. Quit Thunderbird on the other computer.
- If you have had Thunderbird running since you logged in and quit it or it crashed, it may be that it did not exit properly and is still actually running even though you can't see it. At a command prompt run the commands

  $ killall thunderbird-bin

  $ killall thunderbird

  Then try running Thunderbird again.
- You don't have Thunderbird running somewhere else and your profile is marked as being in use even though it isn't. Run Remove Thunderbird Profile Lock from the Application Browser. This will remove the lock file from your profile.

**To quote "Westside" [from here](http://www.windowsbbs.com/firefox-thunderbird-seamonkey/94488-thunderbird-already-running.html):**

> Did you try thunderbird.exe in Processes. You will not see anything in
>   the Application tab, but only under Processes. That happens,
>   frequently, with my Firefox, and removing the .exe, will do the job. I
>   have no idea about restarting the computer. I would expect that it
>   would close the process, but I never tried that approach.

**Another option, that I just made-up:**
Just move that profile you imported and see about importing it from your Thunderbird while it's running..

Comment: Not using Linux; I only have one computer; it's not in the processes; that's a Linux command; that's a Linux command; yes, it's not there, but I will try a restart; Thunderbird, for some silly reason, does not seem to have an option to specify A) Import from Thunderbird and B) the location from which to import.